# Node red Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node-red

I have this problem on a small programm that I don't really understand (I am kinda new to node red), the code is

```
var profile = msg.user.profile;
var cart    = profile.cart = profile.cart || [];
var search  = profile.search;
var id      = msg.payload.substring(8);

for (let item of search){
  if ( item.id != id) continue;
  cart.push(item);
  msg.payload = item;
}
```

And the complete error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined` on the line `for (let item of search){`.
I did some researches and found out that this error usually is due to something that is undefined, but I don't really understand how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using **let** syntax; **let** syntax only available on ecmascript 2015 up (javascript version), so what basically you need to do is to rewrite your code like this

```
var profile = msg.user.profile;
var cart    = profile.cart = profile.cart || [];
var search  = profile.search;
var id      = msg.payload.substring(8);

// assuming that profile.search is an array
for (var i = 0 ; i < search.length ; i++){
  var item = search[i];
  if ( item.id != id) continue;
  cart.push(item);
  msg.payload = item;
}

// if it is an object, then you could loop through its props
for (var prop in search ){
   var item = search[prop];
   if ( item.id != id) continue;
   cart.push(item);
   msg.payload = item;
}
```